# Which is better: using a map inside array list or a pojo class to interact with json response

Tags: android, json, pojo

I'm a bit confused, as from a long time i am saving the json response directly to an ArrayList> and displaying to my listView, but now, looking on other people code i noticed that they are using POJO class to interact with JSON, Is it is better way? if it is please explain why? cause using POJO means I have to write extra code, But if saving the response directly to the arraylist make my work done, then why should i use a POJO class?

Answer (score 1):

1. So, Pojo usage better due to OOP pattern, because you work at runtime with your Java object without intermediate Json parse. Manual json parsing too ugly due to code style(its my opinion).
2. > But if saving the response directly to the arraylist make my work done

If, you collect your object in Maps, you can apply different features out of the box(sort, compare etc) to your map, but in case when your map contains POJO instead of JSONS.

3. Encapsulation. When you work with dates for examples or with type, its pretty good to use getters/setters for data mapping instead of manual parsing again and again.

4.Object scaling and mapping:
 Lets image that we have some object user:

```
public class User{
  int id;

  @SerializedName("specific_id_for_blah_blah")
  private int mSpecId

  @SerializedName("date_of_birthaday")
  private String mBDay;


  public Date getBirthday() {
    return new Date(mBDay); 
  }
}
```

What I want to say by this example.

1. You can map your json to POJO with one line of code only
   `User user = new Gson.fromJson(response, User.class);` 
   Pretty simple isn't?.
2. Name serialization. When your response contain key name which looks to long or weird, you can use your own style naming with easy changes, just with small annotation. mSpecId returns value of "specific_id_for_blah_blah"
3. Platform specific encapsulation. You can use only platform specific object at your runtime, instead parsing operations in your business logic. String with data -> Date or Calendar
4. Also you can override Object methods in your POJO (equals, hashcode, toString) for your logic spec. operations.
5. If your serverside change some key you can change name of key in POJO instead looking through where you parse it before. IN same case you can add new field and setter/getter, if some of parameter will be added to your response

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the serialization part.

Comment: What do you mean under "serialization part" ? Common principles of serialization or annotation @SerializedName?

Comment: I mean How the serialization is implemented here as I can't get how serialization is happening here

Comment: This annotation means that object which will be mapped to field has alternative name/s. Gson parser look through your Json object and get primitive or complicated type. Before getting the object it looking for your variable name. If this name equal to Json key, parser map value to this name, if not, it looking for alternative names which has this annotation. For example if your Json use underline separation, but in code you use camel text, or 'm' suffix as member declaration, you can use this annotation, in opposite case use variable names the same as in Json(camel or underlined ).

Comment: By the way, more details your can find in https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html documentation

Comment: And the last things:
If your Json value has array value -> Gson map it as List<Primitives/Complicated>. If your Json value has another complicated json object -> Gson map it as another POJO object. Try this service http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org  Create some complicated Json and look through generated POJOs, classes. May be it more understandable. So, if my answer was helpful, left the vote please)

Answer (score 0):

There is no right and wrong answer here. It all depends on your use case. If your solution works, and you are happy with it, I don't see why do you need to change it.

If I had to choose, I would go with a POJO class to represent the response, but this is a subjective opinion. I think that you have the following benefits:

1. It's cleaner - having a separate, dedicated class to represent your payload gives you the ability to be more specific in your code. You are no longer manipulating `Map`s of key - value pairs, but instances of a specific class, that can have a more specific behaviour. You can specify natural ordering, criteria for equality, etc - things that may be useful for your program's logic
2. It's simpler - I would prefer calling a getter every time then accessing a map by a property name and getting an Object back. The logic of the program will be much simpler and safer.
3. It's better in terms of OOP best practices - the whole point behind OOP is to have objects, that define properties and behaviours. IMHO, using POJOs to represent responses forces you to adhere more closely to best practices.

There are also some cases that will fit the no - POJO approach better - for example, if you only display your data, not manipulating it in any way inside the app. Or if you want to shave off some time for the complex parsing that may be needed if you are trying to inflate object hierarchies.

My best suggestion is - profile your app, check your use cases and make an educated decision which approach is better.